# Are there conventions around naming entry point groups in Python?

Tags: python, pytest, conventions

Pytest uses the `pytest11` entry point group to automatically discover plugins once they are installed, without the need of any manual configuration by the user.

You can see them via

```py
import pkg_resources

entry_point_group = 'pytest11'

print(f"Plugins in {entry_point_group} entry point group:")
for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group=entry_point_group):
    print(entry_point.name)
```

I'm curious why pytest uses `pytest11` and not just `pytest`. Is there a convention about which entry point group a project uses?

edit: [pygments](https://github.com/pygments/pygments-plugin-scaffolding/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L19-L28) uses the same mechanism, but doesn't have this weird "11" in the name. I guess it's something pytest-specific.